# advance/basic and smartphone views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, view

In a new Rail app I have to consider **2 differents user's type**: basic and Advanced

and I have to create **smartphone views**( unique view for both user's type).

Then I have 3 view/layout:

- web advance
- web basic
- smartphone

I already have the adv/basic flag for the user,
and I followed the RBates tutorial http://asciicasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices.

What is the best way to manage the 3 views/layout ?
What is the best way to use respond_to ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Mobile Fu](http://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu) plugin, it lets you use respond_to like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    render :action => "full" 
  }
  format.mobile {
    render :action => "full",
  }
  format.js {
    render :partial => "content", :layout => false
  }
end
```

But depending on the device, you could create your our format.dumb by hooking into the plugin and:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

Comment: Mobile Fu is very useful,
but I have to manage too the advanced/basic views (not only web standard and mobile views)
thank you,
Alessandro

Comment: Right right --- I was thinking you'd go into the guts of mobile_fu and create a format.smartphone and format.dumbphone based on their decently extensive browser listing.

Course, if there's a better way, I'd love to see it, but customizing mobile_fu works.